# Redirect 301 on changed root name not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to implement a 301 redirect in my roots in order to remove duplicate pages. However i have also changed the root path name from "products" to "produits". Here are my routes:

```
    resources :products, path: "produits" do
      resources :product_variants, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

      collection do
        get :unavailable_products
      end
    end
    get '/products', to: redirect(path: '/produits')
    get '/products/:id', to: redirect('/produits/%{id}')
```

and here are my rails routes:

```
 products GET    /products(.:format)                                                                      redirect(301, path: /produits)
                                      GET    /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  redirect(301, /produits/%{id})
             product_product_variants POST   /produits/:product_id/product_variants(.:format)                                         product_variants#create
          new_product_product_variant GET    /produits/:product_id/product_variants/new(.:format)                                     product_variants#new
         edit_product_product_variant GET    /produits/:product_id/product_variants/:id/edit(.:format)                                product_variants#edit
              product_product_variant PATCH  /produits/:product_id/product_variants/:id(.:format)                                     product_variants#update
                                      PUT    /produits/:product_id/product_variants/:id(.:format)                                     product_variants#update
        unavailable_products_products GET    /produits/unavailable_products(.:format)                                                 products#unavailable_products
                                      GET    /produits(.:format)                                                                      products#index
                                      POST   /produits(.:format)                                                                      products#create
                          new_product GET    /produits/new(.:format)                                                                  products#new
                         edit_product GET    /produits/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             products#edit
                              product GET    /produits/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#show
                                      PATCH  /produits/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#update
                                      PUT    /produits/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#update
                                      DELETE /produits/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#destroy
```

The problem is that i have tried changing the "get '/products', to: redirect(path: '/produits')" to "match" but it gives me the following error:

```
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"
```

How to I redirect all product pages to "produits" and not have a route for "products"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was due to the route order.

The "get '/products', to: redirect(path: '/produits')" and others gets have to be AFTER the resources routes.

The order matters!